# nested conditions in forloop in matlab like c++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am new in matlab, coming from c++ and i am not sure whether it is a valid question to ask. I am trying to write this c++ for loop in matlab, i did study matlab loops but i could not able to found such example as i am illustrating:

for example in c++ we write code like:

```
// this is simple example
int a=1 , b=1;
for(x=0, z=a; x<length; x++, z++){

    for(y=0, w=b; w<length; y++,w++)

      a[x][y]= z*w; 
    }
}
```

now in matlab :

```
z=a;
for x=0:length
    for y=0:length
        a(x,y)=z*w
        w++;   // this is i am trying 
    end
 z++; 
end
```

this is i am trying actually i wanna to increment both 'w' and 'z'

Comment: that's actually absolutely straight-forward. just give it a try and show us what you did. just remember to put the multiple init/increment expressions in separate expressions in matlab.

Comment: First `a` is declared as an `int` then you do `a[x][y]`? (C++ code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `w++` in matlab, you need to use

```
 w = w+1
```